# U-Matrix Code In Matlab

Tags: matlab, som

I am using  Learning vector quantization neural network in Matlab. Is there any code to achieve u-matrix? 
For example after this code

```
[x,t] = iris_dataset;
net = lvqnet(10);
net.trainParam.epochs = 50;
net = train(net,x,t);
view(net)
y = net(x);
perf = perform(net,y,t)
classes = vec2ind(y);
```

How can I see real values of u-matrix.

Thansk a lot.

Comment: What is an **u-matrix**? Can you provide reference? I know LVQ but I don't know what you mean by U-Matrix.

Comment: Here [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-matrix